# AngularJS Factory HTTP Variable Only Usable in View

Tags: angularjs

So, my AngularJS Factory looks like:

```
.factory('getCategories', function($http) {
    return $http.get('api/categories');
})
```

Then, in the controller, I am getting the value like this:

```
getCategories.
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.category_data = data;
    });
```

In the view, I can access the scope variable via {{ category_data }}, and it works fine, returns JSON. But, when I try to access the variable in the controller, it just is always empty. I tried doing this:

```
$scope.category = $scope.category_data;
```

Then, after I had that, I would try to access the $scope.category variable in the view via {{ category }}, and it would be blank.

Any tips on an alternative to what I'm doing? Or what I have done wrong?

**EDIT:** Here is what my whole controller looks like.

```
.controller('ForumController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $filter, getCategories) {  

getCategories.
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.category_data = data;
    });

$scope.category = $scope.category_data;

})
```

Comment: can you show us from which part of the controller you are trying to access the `category_data` variable?

Comment: Basically it's the same as what I have shown above. I have the getCategories.success() blah blah at the very top of the controller, then right under it I have $scope.category = $scope.category_data;

Comment: "when I try to access the variable in the controller, it just is always empty". Are you sure it is after the execution of the `success` handler?

Comment: Yeah it is, I've put the rest of my code in the success handler, and that works now, cause inside a category is topics and I had to get the category name to see which topics were in the category, and having that inside the success handler has fixed the problem. Not sure that's what I want to do, but it works for now at least.

Comment: Referring to Will's answer - the `success` callback is indeed async. So if you would like to access the variable, you'd have to do it in the `success` callback function.
As you can see here in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hLyykgjm/12/), there are two alerts, one outside and one inside the callback. Take note on the order of them going off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `success` callback is asynchronous, it is being executed AFTER the assignment to `$scope.category`, so you're actually assigning a value of `undefined` to `$scope.category`.

You need to do something like this:

```
    .controller('ForumController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $filter, getCategories) {  

    getCategories.
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.category = data;
        });
    })
```